# $x^3+x+m=0$, $x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5=10$, $m=?$

Tags: polynomials, roots, parametric, substitution

### Given the equation:

$x^3+x+m=0$, $m \in R$

$x_1,$ $x_2$ and $x_3$ are roots of the equation,

$x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5=10.$

### Find a value of $m$.

I've applied Vieta's a couple of times and got:

$x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4=2$

$x_1^4x_2^4+x_1^4x_3^4+x_2^4x_3^4=1+4m^2$

$x_1^4x_2^4x_3^4=m^4$

But kind of stopped here, as I don't know how I am supposed to find the sum of odd powers...

Could I have some hints on how to do this? Preferably using the method I tried if it can be done this way, but others will be just as helpful. Thank you.

Comment: $(x+y)^5=x^5+5x^4y+10x^3y^2+10x^2y^3+5xy^4+y^5$ change $y$ with $y+z$ or the variables. You can look it up at pascal's triangle and the binomial relation:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Viete's theorem we obtain:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=0,$$ 
$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=1$$ and
$$x_1x_2x_3=-m.$$
Thus,
$$x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5=-5(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3)x_1x_2x_3=5m,$$
which gives $m=2$.

I used the following statement.

Let $x_1+x_2+x_3=p$, $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=q$ and $x_1x_2x_3=r$.

Thus,
$$x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5=p^5-5p^3q+5pq^2+5u^2r-5qr.$$

Comment: I've used that, but how should I use it in order to get sum of roots^odd powers?

Comment: @Alexander I added something. See now please. By the way, there is an easy way to get it. I can show this way  if you wish. But if you want the answer only then you have it already.

Comment: I still don't get why the last line is true, nor the line above "which gives $m=2$", should I look something up on Wikipedia?

Comment: @Alexander I like to prove inequalities and I just know that if $x_1+x_2+x_3=3u$, $x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=3v^2$ and $x_1x_2x_3=w^3$ then $x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5=243u^5-405u^3v^2+135uv^4+45u^2w^3-15v^2w^3$ and from here I got the line about which  you say. By the way, also there is WA: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SymmetricReduction%5Bx%5E5%2By%5E5%2Bz%5E5,%7Bx,y,z%7D%5D

Comment: I see now, so you used $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^5$. So the above is actually $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^5=x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5-p^5+5p^3q-5pq^2-5u^2r+5qr$, right?

Comment: My above comment was wrong, but I got it anyway :) Thank you.

Comment: @Alexander You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

$x_i^5=-x_i^3-mx_i^2=x_i+m-mx_i^2.$
As $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=-2$, then
$$x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5=3m+2m=5m$$
so $m=2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x^3+x+m=0
&\implies x^5+x^3+mx^2=0\\
&\implies x^5-(x+m)+mx^2=0\\
&\implies m(x^2-1)=x-x^5\\
&\implies m(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-3)=(x_1+x_2+x_3)-(x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5)
\end{align}$$

Now $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ and

$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2-2(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1)=0^2-2\cdot1=-2$$

by Vieta, and $x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5=10$ by assumption, so

$$m(-2-3)=0-10$$

and thus $m=2$.